# Best way to access multiple properties and assign dynamically in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

what is the best way to represent the below properties in Spring for each category? Currently we have implemented for aaa properties. We always have two fields for each category.

We want to use the same POJO for all categories. Please suggest the best approach that fits.

Property file name **package.properties**

```
category.aaa.field1 = value1
category.aaa.field2 = value2

category.bbb.field1 = value1
category.bbb.field2 = value2

category.ccc.field1 = value1
category.ccc.field2 = value2

category.ddd.field1 = value1
category.ddd.field2 = value2
```

We have created a POJO with

```
@Data    
public class CategoryPojo{
    private String valueOne;
    private String valueTwo;

}
```

we are reading it in @Configuration using @PropertySource

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "com.category")
@PropertySource("classpath:package.properties")
public class CategoryConfig{
    @Value("${category.aaa.field1}")
    private String fieldOne;

    @Value("${category.aaa.field2}")
    private String fieldTwo;

    @Bean(name = "getACategory")
    public CategoryPojo getFields() {
        return new CategoryPojo(fieldOne, fieldTwo);
    }

}
```

Comment: As you're using spring boot you can take avantage of https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and should, use https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

To handle this.

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="category")
public class MyProperties{

private CategoryPojo aaa;
private CategoryPojo bbb;
private CategoryPojo ccc;
private CategoryPojo ddd;


@Data    
public static class CategoryPojo{
    private String valueOne;
    private String valueTwo;

}


}
```

You can then place `@EnableConfigurationProperties(classes = MyProperties.class)`  on your main application class or another `@Configuration` and then `@Autowire` your `MyProperties` class where its needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time finding a good solution for my slight variation on this problem. I required a dynamic grouping more like this:

```
category[0].field1 = value1
category[0].field2 = value2

category[1].field1 = value1
category[1].field2 = value2

category[2].field1 = value1
category[2].field2 = value2

category[3].field1 = value1
category[3].field2 = value2
```

So that things can be added to the config file without any associated code changes. Solved it by reading the fields into a list, and manually parsing the keys.

```
@Configuration
public class CategoryConfig {
    private final Environment environment;

    public CategoryConfig(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }


    public List<Category> getCategoryConfigs() {
        List<Category> configs = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            var indexedPropertyKey = format("category.field[%s]", index);

            Long idProperty = environment.getProperty(indexedPropertyKey + ".id", Long.class);
            if (idProperty == null) {
                // No more properties found
                break;
            }

            String nameProperty = environment.getProperty(indexedPropertyKey + ".name");
            configs.add(new Category(idProperty, nameProperty));

            index++;
        }
        return configs;
    }
}
```

I'd hoped there'd be a built in way. But i couldn't find it. Maybe this helps someone.